# Export a MySql Database Into a File

Tags: c#, c++, mysql, database, vba

I created a VBA code which inserts data into my database via mysql on the server. My VBA code will be called by an C++ or C# executable. But if my VBA code fails, I want to restore a backup of my database. So I have some questions:

Is it possible to create a backup file of my db in VBA?
Is it possible to restore this backup file into my main db if my code fails?

If not, are there other approaches or suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can do it easy enough with the command loines tools mysql provided. Me though, I'd be making sure that in teh event of a failure in VBA, no changes would be made...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with MySQL before but it supports [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). You could do a rollback when your code fails and a commit when your code succeeds.